# I can't install "pip install python_bcrypt"

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, bcrypt, face-recognition

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python_bcrypt

I can't install the python_bcrypt in visual studio code anyone know how?

Comment: There are many ways to install python packages in visual studio code. Could you give more detail?
It may be the package is `bcrypt` not `python_bcrypt` (https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/) but without more detail i'm unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is could be an issue of `wheel` package. Some projects don't have wheel package in their source. I tried doing the same on my machine. It's running Python v 3.10.7 and pip v 22.3.1. I faced some warnings but no errors during the installation.

```
pip install python_bcrypt
Collecting python_bcrypt
  Downloading python-bcrypt-0.3.2.tar.gz (19 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: python_bcrypt
  DEPRECATION: python_bcrypt is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for python_bcrypt ... done
Successfully installed python_bcrypt-0.3.2
```

I would say try upgrading your pip, setuptools, wheels

`python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade`

Comment: By the way, the third step is to try to upgrade the tool: `pip install - upgrade setuptools`